# How properly get fixed header + navbar on side + content displayed correctly

Tags: html, css

With my current code i have couple of problems.

1. The NavBar last item `Menu Bottom` is lower underneath the browser window, this is because of the headers height.
2. When scrolling and reaching the bottom, it still allows to scroll more because of that header then header bar disappears.

I'm sure I'm doing a poor job describing all this, but in nutshell:

1. The header needs to be always on top no matter of scroll position and it should not mess up other elements.
2. The contents from NavBar and Content page need to have their in-depended scrolling.

I'm sure I've tried a lot, using position fixed/sticky but i still cant get this right to work.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  overflow: none;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #af6363;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
}

.container-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #6fc06c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #5e9b79;
}

.menu-item_top {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100vmin; */
  height: 100vh;
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #9b5959;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #7c9cb6;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    <header>Header</header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-content">
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu-item_top">
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-item_bottom">
            <div class="menu-item">Menu Bottom</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using `viewport` units which is a good practice but not everywhere if you're trying to achieve what you wanted, I left some comments on the css that was modified. Hope it's what you're looking for.

```css
/*Fills height of the screen*/
body, .main {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
 max-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*Fills height of container*/
.container-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #af6363;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #6fc06c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*Would fill height of the screen not the container*/
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #5e9b79;
}

.menu-item_top {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  /*Would fill height of the screen not the container*/
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #9b5959;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #7c9cb6;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <header>Header</header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-content">
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu-item_top">
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
            <div class="menu-item">Menu</div>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-item_bottom">
            <div class="menu-item">Menu Bottom</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
            <div class="content-item">Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```